# Go: How to prevent pipes from blocking when executing a command via os.exec?

Tags: go, pipe, buffer, exec

In Go version 1.14.2, the following is some sample code which illustrates the often-suggested way to spawn a command, feed data to it via stdin, and then capture its stdout and stderr. It makes use of pipes, but this can cause the program to block if either the stdout or stderr pipe's buffers become full before the process finishes (error handling is omitted in this example) ...

```
func ExecExample(cmd *exec.Cmd, input *[]byte) {
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    err = cmd.Start()
    stdin.Write(*input)
    stdin.Close()
    stdoutBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)
    stderrBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stderr)
    waitErr := cmd.Wait()
}
```

How could this sample code be restructured in Go so that the stdout and stderr pipes never block?

Also, note that I'm looking for a way to separately capture the stdout and stderr output. I do not want them to be combined.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The way to do concurrent things in Go, is with goroutines. But why not [assign `io.Writers` to `Stdout` and `Stderr`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec/?tab=doc#Cmd) like in the [examples](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec/?tab=doc#example-Command) (which handles the goroutines for you automatically)?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do that exact thing. I'm new at Go, so please forgive my ignorance. What, exactly, would I put into cmd.Stdout and cmd.Stderr that would assign io.Writers to them, and how would I capture the bytes after the program completes?

Comment: the linked example in the docs does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks to all. I originally missed the linked example, and now I better understand goroutines.

Answer (score 4):

Let the exec package do the work for you.

```
var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &stdout
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
cmd.Stdin = bytes.NewReader(*input)
err := cmd.Run()
stdoutBytes := stdout.Bytes()
stderrBytes := stderr.Bytes()
```

The exec package creates and manages the goroutines needed to pump data to and from the child process.

[Run it in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M9Yz10vZTHb).

Answer (score 2):

Read one (or both) streams in a goroutine:

```
var stderrBytes []byte
go func() {
  stderrBytes, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(stderr)
}()

err = cmd.Start()
stdoutBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)
```